# POST to PHP from Node.js with image file

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I am trying to POST some data and a file from a Node.js application to a PHP script. I am unable to get the file from PHP side. The request goes through and I get 200 back but PHP thinks the $_FILES array is empty.

My code is

```
var options = {
headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
};
var postData = querystring.stringify(req.body);
var contentLength = postData.length;
options.body = postData;
if (req.files) {
    options.files = { userfile: req.files.userfile };
}
options.headers['Content-Length'] = contentLength;
options.uri = appConfig.url + urlMapping[req.url];
options.method = req.method;

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        res.send(JSON.parse(body));
    }
});
```

Data send to php api

```
{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Content-Length': 155 },
  body: 'first_name=Raju&last_name=Mathai&email_address=rajumathai%40gm.com&mobile_number=9745342931&password=12345&state=Kerala&date_of_birth=12%2F12%2F1988&type=1',
  files: 
   { userfile: 
      { fieldName: 'userfile',
        originalFilename: 'man.png',
        path: '/tmp/CPu0ul670BTtgYXKU07Je_2c.png',
        headers: [Object],
        size: 11288,
        name: 'man.png',
        type: 'image/png' } },
  uri: 'http://192.168.1.102/byker-api-server/webservices/try_new_provider_sign_up.php',
  method: 'POST' }
```

PHP code

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$mobile_number = $_POST['mobile_number'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

$uploadDir = "./uploads/";      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

I am using `multiparty` for parsing form data

Comment: First check if you are sending the file for sure. Try logging the file details in node app before request.

Comment: I think one additional header needs to be set while sending the file: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: @DhruvSaxena not working when i am changing application/x-www-form-urlencoded to multipart/form-data get this error <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: first_name

Comment: @SagarGopale file is there i am sure

Comment: @JihinRaju That appears to be an error from the PHP program which isn't shown here. Also, since `var postData = querystring.stringify(req.body);` is the `POST` data, we could have a few ways to fix the error. (1) Checking whether PHP really needs `first_name` and removing the code from it if it doesn't. Or, (2) If it is needed AND it has to come from this program then, as a plausibility (which can't be confirmed without seeing the code), you might have to add an element called `first_name` in the `body` tag

Comment: @DhruvSaxena i have updated the question pls see the body data

Comment: Thanks. Have you access to the PHP code too? Could you confirm if `first_name` is accessed as `$_POST['first_name']` and not `$_GET['first_name']`? I can't see any other issues apart from that.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena i have updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135304/discussion-between-dhruv-saxena-and-jihin-raju).